# In JointJs, how can I move a all elements together by dragging an embedded element?

Tags: javascript, hierarchy, diagram, jointjs

I'm using JointJs to create a diagram.

When I create an element with a number of embedded elements, I can easily drag them all by dragging the parent. However, when I drag the children, they move on their own. How can I move the parent and all children by dragging either the parent or one of the children elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a little bit tricky:

https://jsfiddle.net/vtalas/xk73L947/

the magic is in this part:

```
paper.on('cell:pointermove', function (cellView, evt) {

  if (cellView.model.isLink()) {
    return ;
  }

  var parent = cellView.model.getAncestors()[0];

  // if we trying to move with embedded cell 
  if (parent) {

    // cancel move for the child (currently dragged element)
    cellView.pointerup(evt);
    var view = paper.findViewByModel(parent);

    // substitute currently dragged element with the parent
    paper.sourceView = view;

    // get parent's position and continue dragging (with the parent, children are updated automaticaly)
    var localPoint = paper.snapToGrid({ x: evt.clientX, y: evt.clientY });
    view.pointerdown(evt, localPoint.x, localPoint.y);
  }
});
```

Comment: To substitute the current view being dragged is an excellent hack. Thanks!

Comment: This works with JointJS, but not with RappidJS. RappidJS adds some extra functionality to joint.dia.paper.pointermove which causes the child element to move a little before the parents movement is recognized / initiated by the event listener. I had to overwrite rappids pointermove method in order to solve this issue.

Comment: @LucianDepold can you share some code how did you overwrite rappids pointer move?

Comment: You can do this by creating your own paper, like so: GraphVER_rappid_dia_Paper = joint.dia.Paper.extend({

pointermove(evt) {
// Pointermove code in here
}
});

Comment: this method seems to work only up to 2.0. It doesn't work Jointjs version 2.1 and above.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new interactive option `stopDelegation` in `v3.1` ([documentation](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.1/joint.html#dia.Paper.prototype.options.interactive)). If set to `false` the dragging of an element is delegated to its parent.

```
paper.setInteractivity({ stopDelegation: false });
```